# Stripe Checkout is missing the required `key` parameter in React

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I'm integrating Stripe checkout with my project(React), but when I proceed with the payment, I get this error stating "key" is missing. I can't really figure out what am I missing here. I'm following the **react stripe checkout** documentation at https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-stripe-checkout

[image]
[image]

My **.env** file has :

> REACT_APP_STRIPE='myPublishable key'
> [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you find the way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should put the private key in api env file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your .env file is in the root.
2. Variable name should start with "REACT_APP_"
3. While writing the value to the variable don't give space like
   REACT_APP_KEY =pk_key....
4. Stop the react npm server and restart it to let the server know about the .env file.